# Can an Antivirus delete files inside an archive?

Tags: anti-virus, file-archiver

If an Antivirus (ex:ESET) detects a virus inside an archive (ex: .RAR) will it automatically delete the infected file? Or would I need to delete the whole archive? (assuming the archive is not password protected)

Comment: It depends on the virusscanner, but usually it will quarantine the entire archive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's worth a few sentences to first comment on how most security products approach archives:

Most endpoint real-time/on-access scanners (by default) don't fully scan archives due to the overhead of the unpacking in real-time, plus the "containers" don't really pose any "immediate" threat so it's not worth the performance hit for the gain of just potentially detecting something sooner.

That said most products provide an option to enable scanning of archives in real-time but more often than not it would be not recommended.

Most solutions contain multiple layers to protect the computer and to prevent such a file getting on to the computer in the first instance.  For example most solutions have a hook to scan files as they are downloaded by the browser and before being written to disk, maybe in some web-proxy process that sits in front of the browser process.  As this scanning isn't as time sensitive more time can be taken and most would have "zip-bomb" detection to prevent resource exhaustion if that was the "attack".

For example, no one really cares about an extra 3 seconds in a file download but if a process is blocked from reading a file from disk for 3 seconds that will not go unnoticed and you will likely feel the hang as a file request is temporarily blocked in the kernel pending a virus scan.  The same may go for downloading email attachments, again speed is less of a concern.

This also goes for any security product such as an appliance (web/email/etc..) upstream of the endpoint.  They have time to scan in the archive if they can in order to take action.

Assuming the archive file has made it to disk and the front line has failed or the detection signature/method is new; as part of the unpacking process the real-time/on-access scanner would be scanning each file as it is unpacked. It would be picked up then by the real-time scanner.

Archive file types are usually (by default) scanned at the endpoint as part on scheduled scans or on-demand and this is usually when you get the message, i.e. following the completion of a scheduled scan.  The scanners may just say it's password protected if it and they are unable to unpack it, the real-time component would pick it up here as the user provides the password.  If they can scan the contents on-demand, the products usually report a full path to the infected object within the container.

Most products give you the option to configure what happens on detection for each of the detected components, i.e. real-time, on-demand/scheduled scans.  Most try to cleanup the threat first if a clean-up routine has been written for the threat in question, before just blocking/quarantining if no action can be taken.

As before with the real-time scanning inside archive option; you can usually configure to automatically delete files on detection but with the risk of a false positive most vendors will not delete by default.

So the options for the end user are one or more of the following:

1. Delete the entire archive file if you don't need it.  An example might be a file in your Downloads directory you don't need.
2. If you think it's a false positive (maybe based on age, detection name, file detected, location on disk, intuition and experience required), you can usually send a sample to the vendor.  Note: Depending on the vendors signature/method of detection, you may need to send the entire archive rather than just the file within.
3. Upload maybe both the archive and the detected object withing to virustotal.com as a second opinion.
4. If you need the other files in the archive, they you may need to authorize/exclude the file and or destination location in order to unpack it before carefully deleting the detected element.  You can then zip it back up but depending on the purpose of the archive, you may have just rendered it useless if the detected component you removed is required.

Given the above, I think it's fair to say that most products don't by default re-pack an archive based on the detection of a component within.  If however there was a piece of malware that spread by placing itself into say a docx container, then the vendor, given a sample could easily write a cleanup routine that would remove just the threat from the archive.  So I think the answer here is not by default but given a sample and enough reason to do so it might.